# How do I send form field values to a php mysql query in wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, forms, form-submit

I have a table in my wordpress install that stores a lot of data.  I have a php file that can run a query on the table and return a nicely filtered selection of rows. I have a form on my wordpress page that allows users to select a variety of values corresponding to the mysql query variables.  How do I get the php file to use the values selected in the form?

my form uses the following:

```
<input type="text" name="max_price" />
<input type="text" name="loan_fraction" />
<input type="text" name="interest_rate" />
<input type="text" list="state" />
```

I don't really know what sort of submit action I need but I want it to pass these values to my php that uses them like:

```
$values = mysql_query("select
    b.listing, b.bed, b.bath, b.type, b.address, b.postcode, b.state, b.price, avg_rent
from
    buy_items b
        join
    (SELECT
        bed, bath, type, suburb, postcode, AVG(price) as avg_rent
    FROM
        rent_items
    GROUP BY bed, bath , type , suburb , postcode) a ON a.bed = b.bed and a.bath = b.bath
        and a.suburb = b.suburb
        and a.postcode = b.postcode
    and a.type = b.type
where
    (b.price * some_number) < a.avg_rent
  and b.price > 50000
  and price < max_price
  and b.state = state");
```

where some_number is a function of loan_fraction and interest_rate.

Thanks :)

Comment: your question is ambigius, other thing is you should not use mysql_query in wordpress instead use `$wpdb->query` to make database queries . for more info google `wordpress wpdb class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setting the action to point to the php file, and assigning the field names to variables in the php seemed to work:

In HTML:

```
<td>
  <form id="buy_prop" action="http://****_data.php" method="post">How much are you willing to spend?
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="max_price" id="max_price">
</td>
```

In PHP

```
$max_price = $_POST["max_price"];    
$loan_fraction = $_POST["loan_fraction"];
etc etc
```